# Windows Batch Script to Move XML files to multiple folders in some balanced manner

Tags: windows

I have 4,043,777 XML Files (40 GB in size) in date wise folders. Each day folder contains approximate 1000 xml files. My reporting application requires these xml files in folders named Data1, Data2, Data3 and Data4 for processing the xml to Database.  Whenever each xml reaches in data folder it will be processed and moved to some other processed folders of each data folder. Can anybody help me with some kind of batch script,  that can move the xml files to these data folders in balanced manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch script will move your xml files evenly into directories Data1, Data2, Data3 and Data4:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a i=1
for %%f in (%1) do (
  copy %%f %2!i!
  set /a i=i+1
  if "!i!" == "5" set /a i=1
)    
endlocal
```

Call it something like this:

```
>mybatfile D:\OldPoslogBackup\Datewise\*.xml D:\OldPoslogBackup\test
```

To copy all xml files in `D:\OldPoslogBackup\Datewise` equally to the four directories named `D:\OldPoslogBackup\test1-4`

This works by setting up a variable `i` that iterates repeatedly over the values 1-4 as each matching file is handled, ie the values assigned to `i` are `1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,...` etc

Of course you may have to adjust the source `(*.xml)` and action `move %%f Data!i!` to suit your exact situation.

Comment: can you tell me how can i give the source and destination path.

Comment: I have used path as 'for /r %%F in (D:\OldPoslogBackup\Datewise) do' but the resultant copy command showing 'copy D:\OldPoslogBackup\Datewise\04-06-2013\D:\OldPoslogBackup\Datewise D:\OldPoslogBackup\test1!i!' Here the half portion of the path is what exactly i need, but its appended with the root directory. So the complete path became meaningless. Can you tell me how to avoid this error?

Comment: OK. I've tested this and it now works. The problem was the `/r`. I've also changed it so you can call it with two parameters. The first is the wildcarded fileset, the second is the stem of the target directories. See updated answer.